# Two dimensional array- Session

Tags: java, session, int

I have a two dimensional matrix which I want to add to the `session`. To add an Integer to the `session` object the syntax is

`session.setAttribute("Mat", mat);
int matr = (Integer) session.getAttribute("Mat");`

Searched a lot for the syntax to add `int[][]` to `session`. Firstly can we add, if yes any idea on how to go forward with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one :-

```
int[][] 2darr = new int[2][3];
session.setAttribute("2darr", 2darr );
int[][] 2darrFromSession = (int[][]) session.getAttribute("2darr");
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys.. That completes my project .. Was stuck with it from long :) :)

Comment: @Jil glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You essentially add Objects to session. Doesn't matter if it is an integer or 2D integer array ... The syntax for adding should be the same

```
session.setAttribute("Mat", mat);
```

where mat is a 2D integer array

```
int mat[][] = new int[3][10]; //just an example
```

Now, To fetch it

```
int[][] ret = (int[][])session.getAttribute("Mat");
```

Hopefully that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much .. That completes my project .. Was stuck with it from long :) :)

Comment: @Jil ... glad to help :)